# Trying to parse a Json, but getting undefined

Tags: json, node.js, websocket

I am using a simple request to an api that gives back market details on the site. 
I was able to get the trading pairs on the site but I am having trouble saving the rate to a variable. Let alone being able to print it out alone as I keep on getting undefined when trying to print the rate variable.

Here is the following code I have attempted to write to gather this information.

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://api.quadrigacx.com/public/info',(err,response,payload) => {
try{

var json = JSON.parse(payload);
//console.log(json);
for( var market in json){
    var base = market.split('_')[0].toUpperCase();
    var quote = market.split('_')[1].toUpperCase(); 
    //var rate = json.market.rate; 
    var temp = market + ':'
    //console.log(rate + "\r\n");
    console.log(json.temp);
    //console.log(temp);

    }
}catch(err){
    console.log("QuadrigaCX parsing error");
    console.log(payload);
    }
});
```

The Json is printed out as shown:

```
{ btc_cad: 
{ rate: '9126.99',
 volume: '455.29246286',
 sell: '9198.99',
 buy: '9145.00' },
 btc_usd: 
{ rate: '7135.00',
 volume: '27.94442250',
 sell: '7239.99',
 buy: '7135.00' },
eth_btc: 
{ rate: '0.04140000',
 volume: '3068.52782310',
 sell: '0.04187304',
 buy: '0.04102924' },
eth_cad: 
{ rate: '381.00',
 volume: '1710.79836900',
 sell: '383.00',
 buy: '380.55' },
ltc_cad: 
{ rate: '75.00',
 volume: '7151.43653780',
 sell: '75.00',
 buy: '74.01' },
 bch_cad: 
{ rate: '797.36',
 volume: '865.01121761',
 sell: '799.89',
 buy: '785.00' } }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print rate this what you need to do:

```
for( var market in json){      
   console.log(json[market]["rate"]);   
}
```